# Vue.js, vuex with Firebase cloud firestore, updating the front end after adding or removing any record from the database

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

Two questions

1. I want to update the front end after committing any action to my firestore database, lets say i have a collection of items that I render to my front end via a getter from store.js file. and in my .vue component, I have a functionality to add or remove or update the items coming from the database, the functionality is working fine but I would have to refresh the page to have the updates reflected in my app, the code below is a simple example of in a .vue component

```js
export default {
  //....
  
  computed:{
    items: {
      return this.$store.getters.Items 
    }
  },
  methods :{
    removeItem(id) {
      this.$store.dispatch('removeItem', id)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<template> 
<div >
  <ul v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <li> {{item.name}} <button @click="removeItem(item.id)">X</button></li> 
  </ul>
    
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is an example of my store.js file

```js
import db from 'firebase/init.js'

state: {
  items: []
},

mutations: {
  SETMENUITEMS(state, items) {
    state.items = items
  }
  REMOVEITEM(state, id) {
    state.menuItems.filter(item => {
      return item.id != id
    })
  }
},

actions: {
  //I dispatch this action  in the created life hook of my root .vue app component to have the items loaded upon initilizing the app
  fetchMenuItems({commit}){
    const menuItems = []
      db.collection('myCollection').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            let item = doc.data()
            item.id = doc.id;
            menuItems.push(item)
          })
          commit('SETMENUITEMS', menuItems)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
  },
  removeItem({commit}, id){
    db.collection('myCollection').doc(id).delete()
      .then(() => {
        //at this point the item is already deleted from the database but since the ap didn't reload the item is still showing 
        commit('REMOVEITEM', id)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message)
  }
},

getters: {
  Items: state => state.items
}
```

2. Now, could someone tell me how to simply remove an entire collection from the firestore and also have the result reflected in my front end.

kindly leave a comment below for any further clarification about the desired behavior, sorry for the long question and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer the first question.

you are committing to the store as a promise is resolved.
I think the promise is resolved only once.

Try to attach your code directly to the collection with onSnapshot so you can pass the observer directly the the collection observable:

...

```
actions: {
  //I dispatch this action  in the created life hook of my root .vue app component to have the items loaded upon initilizing the app
  fetchMenuItems({commit}){
    const menuItems = []
      db.collection('myCollection').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            let item = doc.data()
            item.id = doc.id;
            menuItems.push(item)
          })
          commit('SETMENUITEMS', menuItems)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
  },
  removeItem({commit}, id){
    db.collection('myCollection').doc(id).delete()
      .then(() => {
        //at this point the item is already deleted from the database but since the ap didn't reload the item is still showing 
        commit('REMOVEITEM', id)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message)
  }
},
```

...

about removing an entire collection it is not reccomended from a web client as you can see in the doc: [Delete data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data)